# PySpark Dynamically Explode Nested Columns - change from using FOR to more optimal solution

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

Running on AWS Glue using PySpark. I need to dynamically explode nested columns within a dataframe. Using a for loop and I want to convert it to a map/reduce function but this is still fairly new to me. Any guidance would be great.

This the structure of the data I am reading in - I have no control over it as it lands. I can however change it whilst the code is running, I think that's what I need to do but I'm at my wits end trying to write this.

```
root
 |-- uniqueId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- modifiedDate: string (nullable = true)
 |-- properties: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- attribute1: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- sourceId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- versions: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- timestamp: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- attribute2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- sourceId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- versions: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- timestamp: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- attribute3: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- sourceId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- versions: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- timestamp: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- attribute4: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- sourceId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- versions: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- timestamp: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

I need to explode the **versions** of each nested property to end up with a structure like this:

```
root
 |-- uniqueId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- modifiedDate: string (nullable = true)
 |-- propertyName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: long (nullable = true)
```

For each and **every** attribute that exists in properties in my data structure.

E.G:

Take a dataframe that looks like this:

```
+-----------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
|modifiedDate           |properties                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |uniqueId|
+-----------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
|2021-08-13 10:22:34.251|[[1234, [[A1, 1628850142573, A1]]], [1224, [[A2, 1628850142573, A2]]], [1234, [[A3, 1628850142573, A3 v1], [A3, 1628850142573, A3 v2]]], [1234, [[A4, 1628850142573, A4 v1], [A4, 1628850159594, A4 v2], [A4, 1628880142573, A4 v3]]]]|123     |
+-----------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
```

To this:

```
+--------+-----------------------+------------+----+-------------+-----+
|uniqueId|modifiedDate           |propertyName|name|timestamp    |value|
+--------+-----------------------+------------+----+-------------+-----+
|123     |2021-08-13 10:22:34.251|attribute1  |A1  |1628850142573|A1   |
|123     |2021-08-13 10:22:34.251|attribute2  |A2  |1628850142573|A2   |
|123     |2021-08-13 10:22:34.251|attribute3  |A3  |1628850142573|A3 v1|
|123     |2021-08-13 10:22:34.251|attribute3  |A3  |1628850142573|A3 v2|
|123     |2021-08-13 10:22:34.251|attribute4  |A4  |1628850142573|A4 v1|
|123     |2021-08-13 10:22:34.251|attribute4  |A4  |1628850142573|A4 v2|
|123     |2021-08-13 10:22:34.251|attribute4  |A4  |1628850142573|A4 v3|
+--------+-----------------------+----+------------+-------------+-----+
```

The way I can **currently** trying to achieve this is querying properties.* to a dataframe, getting a list of all properties, looping through those properties and exploding properties.**property_name**.versions and unioning in to a data frame.

Safe to say it's not optimise and needs fixing. Here's the sample code:

```
import sys
import datetime
from functools import reduce
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
glueContext = GlueContext(spark)

## Starting Example of the data
newJson = '{"uniqueId": 123,"modifiedDate": "2021-08-13 10:22:34.251","properties": {"attribute1": {"sourceId": "1234","versions": [{"name": "A1","value": "A1","timestamp": 1628850142573}]},"attribute2": {"sourceId": "1224","versions": [{"name": "A2","value": "A2","timestamp": 1628850142573}]},"attribute3": {"sourceId": "1234","versions": [{"name": "A3","value": "A3 v1","timestamp": 1628850142573},{"name": "A3","value": "A3 v2","timestamp": 1628850142573}]},"attribute4": {"sourceId": "1234","versions": [{"name": "A4","value": "A4 v1","timestamp": 1628850142573},{"name": "A4","value": "A4 v2","timestamp": 1628850159594},{"name": "A4","value": "A4 v3","timestamp": 1628880142573}]}}}'
df_ex = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize([newJson]))
## uncomment here to see the example
#df_ex.printSchema()
#df_ex.show(truncate=False)


## how I want the example to end up
newJson = '[{"uniqueId": 123,"modifiedDate": "2021-08-13 10:22:34.251","propertyName": "attribute1","name": "A1","value": "A1","timestamp": 1628850142573},{"uniqueId": 123,"modifiedDate": "2021-08-13 10:22:34.251","propertyName": "attribute2","name": "A2","value": "A2","timestamp": 1628850142573},{"uniqueId": 123,"modifiedDate": "2021-08-13 10:22:34.251","propertyName": "attribute3","name": "A3","value": "A3 v1","timestamp": 1628850142573},{"uniqueId": 123,"modifiedDate": "2021-08-13 10:22:34.251","propertyName": "attribute3","name": "A3","value": "A3 v2","timestamp": 1628850142573},{"uniqueId": 123,"modifiedDate": "2021-08-13 10:22:34.251","propertyName": "attribute4","name": "A4","value": "A4 v1","timestamp": 1628850142573},{"uniqueId": 123,"modifiedDate": "2021-08-13 10:22:34.251","propertyName": "attribute4","name": "A4","value": "A4 v2","timestamp": 1628850142573},{"uniqueId": 123,"modifiedDate": "2021-08-13 10:22:34.251","propertyName": "attribute4","name": "A4","value": "A4 v3","timestamp": 1628850142573}]'
df_wanted_ex = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize([newJson]))
## uncomment here to see how i want the data at the end
#df_wanted_ex.printSchema()
#df_wanted_ex.show(truncate=False)

schema = StructType([
    StructField("uniqueId", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("propertyName", StringType(), True),
    StructField("name", StringType(), True),
    StructField("value", StringType(), True),
    StructField("timestamp", StringType(), True),
    StructField("modifiedDate", StringType(), True)
])

stagingdf = spark.createDataFrame([], schema)
stagingdf1 = spark.createDataFrame([], schema)

df_ex_props = df_ex.select("properties.*")
selectcolumns = ["uniqueId","propertyName","properties.name","properties.value","properties.timestamp","modifiedDate"]
for count, prop in enumerate(df_ex_props.columns):  
    stagingdf1 = df_ex.select("uniqueId", F.lit(prop).alias("propertyName"), "modifiedDate", F.explode("properties." + prop + ".versions").alias("properties")).select(*selectcolumns)
    stagingdf = stagingdf.union(stagingdf1)

stagingdf.show(10, truncate=False)
```

When I run this on AWS Glue using PySpark it gives me how I want the data however it's not optimal. I'd like to convert it to a map/lambda but can't get my head around how to do it.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: why do you think this solution is not optimal? You are selecting a column and exploding it. If you use relationalize it will work on entire data

Comment: I don't quite understand your question sorry. I want this to work on entire data, I.E. I want to take the properties from the data and explode the versions and get the final table.

Using a for loop doesn't seem a smart like the most efficient way of using spark.

Comment: Using a for loop to handle dynamic variables is a common pattern and completely optimal. Remember that Spark is lazy and will do any computation until an action triggers it.

Comment: @Gaarv thanks for your reply. I've been working with this on and off - the issue I found was the writing of the data frame back to an RDS. The code runs in 3 mins, when I then write it to an RDS it takes much, much longer.

Hopefully I will get my head around it. Good to know I was following the right practices for the code though!